# Diferencias entre strpos, strstr y preg_match

Tags: php, string

PHP ofrece numerosos métodos para averiguar si una cadena de texto contiene otra subcadena:

- [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php): para buscar la primera ocurrencia
- [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php): para encontrar la última ocurrencia
- [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php): para buscar la primera ocurrencia
- [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php): para buscar usando (o no) con expresiones regulares
- ...

¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre ellos (especialmente `strpos` y `strstr`)? ¿Hay alguno que sea más rápido? ¿Cuál de ellos es más recomendable o depende de la situación?

Comment: ¿Te refieres en cuanto a rapidez entre ellos verdad? Las diferencias creo que son claras con las propias definiciones.

Comment: Rapidez, sí. Y también la diferencia entre `strpos` y `strstr`, las dos parecen hacer lo mismo, pero realmente no es el caso

Comment: Algunas  referencia en Inglés http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820586/which-method-is-preferred-strstr-or-strpos ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433492/preg-match-vs-strpos-for-match-finding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En cuanto a funcionalidad se refiere, dependería de lo que quisieras encontrar.

Por ejemplo, vamos a buscar el elemento "mundo" dentro de esta cadena (puedes comprobar que he puesto dos veces la palabra mundo dentro de la cadena):

```
$string = "jersiojresoiresmundojrepiojreopsijreposijmundorpeosijreoisj";
```

Y vamos a aplicarle los diferentes métodos, los cuales parecen similares, pero no son iguales:

***strpos***

```
echo strpos($string, "mundo"); //Devuelve 15, la POSICIÓN de la primera ocurrencia
```

***strrpos***

```
echo strrpos($string, "mundo"); //Devuelve 41, la POSICIÓN de la última ocurrencia.
```

***strstr***

```
echo strstr($string, "mundo"); //Devuelve "mundojrepiojreopsijreposijmundorpeosijreoisj", es decir, todo el String desde la primera ocurrencia
```

**preg_match**

```
echo preg_match("/mundo/i", $string); //Devuelve 1 ya que ha encontrado la cadena dentro del string. En caso contrario, marcaría un 0

echo preg_match("/casa/i", $string); //Devuelve 0
```

En cuanto a si es más rápido `strpos` o `strstr`, tal y como indica la documentación de PHP para el caso de [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php):

> Si solo se quiere saber si un needle determinado aparece en un haystack, se utiliza la función **strpos()** que es más rápida y requiere menos memoria.

Answer (score 4):

> Benchmark PHP

**Entorno de prueba:**

- PHP 7.0.11
- NGINX 1.11.5
- iMac 3,4 GHz Intel Core i7 / 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 / macOS Sierra 10.12.1

---

**Funcíon de prueba:**

```
$randomString = 'KWFuPHrOoLzcVMVpTFooczSsXvztgORWRYhApKbMvRFLexLOKLLBarQqUpCCPZiqHipTaK';
                                //^^^Foo                          //^^^Bar 
$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) { // iteración 10 milliones

    // Método
}

echo 'Tiempo:  '.number_format(( microtime(true) - $start), 4).' segundos';
```

**Resultado:**

> Método: strpos()

- `strpos($randomString, 'Foo');` - `Tiempo: 0.5009 segundos`
- `strpos($randomString, 'Bar');` - `Tiempo: 0.4699 segundos`

> Método: strrpos()

- `strrpos($randomString, 'Foo');` - `Tiempo: 0.7650 segundos`
- `strrpos($randomString, 'Bar');` - `Tiempo: 0.4894 segundos`

> Método: strstr()

- `strstr($randomString, 'Foo');` - `Tiempo: 1.0125 segundos`
- `strstr($randomString, 'Bar');` - `Tiempo: 0.9465 segundos`

> Método: preg_match()

- `preg_match('/Foo/', $randomString);` - `Tiempo: 1.1475 segundos`
- `preg_match('/Bar/', $randomString);` - `Tiempo: 1.0569 segundos`

  *in-sensitive string matching:*
- `preg_match('/Foo/i', $randomString);` - `Tiempo: 1.1483 segundos`
- `preg_match('/Bar/i', $randomString);` - `Tiempo: 1.1304 segundos`